Is the dirac-delta as test function in the functional derivative imperative?
On wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) the functional differential of a functional, $F: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, w.r.t. a function $g \in \mathbb{R}$ (where $B$ denotes the Banach space) is defined as
\begin{align}
\delta F = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F[g + \varepsilon \phi] - F[g]}{\varepsilon},
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi \in B$ is a test-function. On the other hand, I often see (e.g. here: Definition of functional derivative with dirac delta function) the functional derivative defined as in the expression above but with the difference, that $\phi$ is explicitly given as the dirac-delta, i.e.
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta F}{\delta g(x)} = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{F[g(y) + \varepsilon \delta(y-x)] - F[g(y)]}{\varepsilon}.
\end{align}
I understand that the dirac-delta is convenient when the functional involves an integral. What I wondering is the following: Is $\phi = \delta$ merely a choice? Or are there some reasons that I have to take $\phi = \delta$? On the same note, could I take any $\phi$ and just write $\phi(y -x)$?

I have never seen any definition of the functional derivative involving a delta function. The linked post refers to a physics book "for gifted amateurs" so I suspect they are cutting some corners and simplifying a derivation somehow. In particular, $\delta$ is not an element of most Banach spaces of functions so evaluating $F$ at it doesn't even make sense. I would not try to seriously use this unless you had a very specific reason to do so

I actually want to avoid using the dirac-delta. My intention for asking the question is to be sure that it is justified to avoid it and your comment helps me in this regard!
